# Как решить проблему подключения Boost при конфигурировании cmake?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Пытаю подключить библиотеки boost asio к своему проекту. Но сталкиваюсь с проблемой при конфигурировании
Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version

Два дня гуглил эту проблему, но решить так и не удалось. С C++ только начинаю работать.
[New cmake warning about BOOST](https://github.com/dealii/dealii/issues/3765)

[CMake finds Boost but the imported targets not ava...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123509/cmake-finds-boost-but-the-imported-targets-not-available-for-boost-version)

Понял что Boost 1.65 and 1.65.1 require CMake 3.9.3 or newer. Однако обновление cmake до 3.12.1 не дает результатов.

Прошу помощи или подсказки в этом вопросе.

Система: Ubuntu 18.04
libboost: 1.65.1.0ubuntu1
cmake version 3.12.1 (обновил)

Код простого проекта

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main() {

std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream("google.com", "http");
stream << "GET /ip HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\nConnection: closer\n\r\n";
std::cout << stream.rdbuf();

return 0;
}
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(ticker)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set (BOOST_ROOT "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")

set (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set (BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK OFF)

find_package (Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)

if (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif ()

add_executable(ticker main.cpp)

target_link_libraries (ticker ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

При попытке компиляции я получаю следующее

```
cmake ticker
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning at /opt/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:959 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /opt/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1618 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /opt/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:959 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /opt/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1618 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2044 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ivan/Projects/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: устанавливать что-либо в обход менеджера пакетов, если не понимаешь, что **в точности** делаешь — отличный способ прострелить себе ногу...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Верно подмечено

Answer (score 1):

У Вас BOOST_ROOT указан явно неправильно. Если указываете BOOST_ROOT, то у Вас должны быть файлы $(BOOST_ROOT)/include/boost/version.hpp и $(BOOST_ROOT)/lib/libboost_system.a (как вариант $(BOOST_ROOT)/lib/libboost_system.so).

Если у Вас boost установлен из пакета, то имеет смысл попробовать совсем не указывать BOOST_ROOT, cmake в теории должен все находить сам.

Если удаление BOOST_ROOT не помогает, то надо отдельно выставить BOOST_INCLUDEDIR (у Вас должен быть файл $(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR)/boost/version.hpp) и BOOST_LIBRARYDIR (в этом названии я не уверен, но как-то так; должен быть файл $(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR)/libboost_system.a или so).

На самом деле там необходимых файлов намного больше, я указал самые очевидные. Так что не имеет смысла копировать эти файлы в другие папки. Нужно именно найти где они лежат и указать соответствующие переменные.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Вы оказались отчасти правы, пришлось установить последний boost и прописать BOOST_INCLUDEDIR и BOOST_LIBRARYDIR

например так

set (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/opt/boost_1_68_0")
set (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/opt/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib")